# smooth loading of the heavy scene in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#

I have a very very **big/huge scene** to load, I can't load it at once. So what I know I have applied but it still loading takes  some time I want to make it smooth. How it possible?

What i have tried so far is **I divided the scene into multiple scenes and loading it into async manner as my character controller move.** I am moving my character controller and accordingly loading (its near)scenes by matching its position.

How do i load smoothly a big scene? what will be the strategy? Is this right strategy which I am doing or there any else solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Application.LoadLevelAdditive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html)

> Unlike LoadLevel, LoadLevelAdditive does not destroy objects in the
>   current level. Objects from the new level are added to the current
>   scene. This is useful for creating continuous virtual worlds, where
>   more content is loaded in as you walk through the environment.

Comment: its Obsolete Use SceneManager.LoadScene as doc told

Comment: if i use this and not unload my other scene then it should be heavy and i dont have enough ram

Answer (score 0):

Like [dnk drone.vs.drones](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/62256/dnk-drone-vs-drones) said, LoadLevelAdditive is likely going to help with how you've got it set up currently.

You might want to look into something more like a chunk-based loading system, however.  Only rendering near chunks and using appropriate LOD's seems to be more standard in the industry.  I've got a feeling it's better for your performance as well, but I'm not too sure on the specifics of how Unity handles LoadLevelAdditive.

Comment: if i use this and not unload my other scene then it should be heavy and i dont have enough ram

Comment: Correct.  After walking far enough away from the old scene, you will want to unload/destroy the old scene objects.

Comment: Correct but as scene start loading my character controller suddenly stuck at the moment

Comment: Interesting.  I've never used the LoadLevelAdditive approach personally.  That's why I'd steer you more towards using chunks and LOD's.  You get more control out of it that way, and it's likely going to be overall better.